# Python: Group single column by distinct value

Tags: python, sql, group-by

I have a sqlite database like so with the column titles and data:

```
expiration, title
2015-08-15, example title
2015-08-15, another sample title
2015-08-15, another one
2015-08-16, lorem ipsum
2015-08-16, example
```

Is there a way to group by the expiration date so it would result in something like:

```
Expiring 2015-08-15
    example title
    another sample title
    another one
Expiring 2015-08-16
    lorem ipsum
    example
```

Currently here is what I have:

```
cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM expiration WHERE exp BETWEEN date('now','-1 days') AND date('now','+6 days') ORDER BY exp")
    sql.commit()
    row = cur.fetchall()
    for res  in row:
        msg += res[1] + "\n"
    print msg
```

But it does not group by date, it just lists all the titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely achieve this grouping operation in sql, but without digging into sqlite specifics, it would also be easy to do the grouping in python like so:

```
import itertools as it

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM expiration WHERE exp BETWEEN date('now','-1 days') AND date('now','+6 days') ORDER BY exp")
sql.commit()
row = cur.fetchall()
for i,g in it.groupby(row, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    msg += 'Expiring %s%s\n' % (i, '\n\t'.join(x[1] for x in g))
print msg
```

Comment: I am getting `('ERROR:', TypeError("'itertools._grouper' object has no attribute '__getitem__'",))`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test.  I think my edit should fix it now.

Comment: Same thing. I commented out everything in the loop and it still has same error.

Comment: Also, `i` does not seem to be used and that holds the date

Comment: I got it. Your mistake was with `g=list(g[1])`. You can remove that line and replace the second line with `msg += 'Expiring %s%s\n' % (i, '\n\t'.join(x[1] for x in g))` (note `i` instead of `g[0]`

Comment: Ah yes, should've tested better before posting :)  The post is all fixed up now, thanks @Bijan

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not output results in indented grouped structure but in tabular format of rows and columns.

Consider using [groupby()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in Python's data analysis package, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), which works seamlessly with sqlite:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
dataframe = pandas.read_sql("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM expiration \
                             WHERE exp BETWEEN date('now','-1 days') \
                             AND date('now','+6 days') \
                             ORDER BY exp", conn)

expdategroup = dataframe.groupby(['exp', 'title'])
print(expdategroup['title'].count())
```

With the below output (aggregate here is counting titles in each exp date):

```
exp         title  
2015-08-15  example title         5
            another sample title  3
            another one           6
            lorem ipsum           4
            example               2
2015-08-16  example title         2
            another sample title  2
            another one           1
            lorem ipsum           4
            example               7
            ...
```

Alternatively, you can use pandas [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) still counting here using the length aggregate function. This solution requires another variable (great chance to add numeric figures to `sum()`, `mean()`, etc.):

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='othervar', index=['exp', 'title'], aggfunc=len)
print(table)
```

Roughly same output:

```
exp         title  
2015-08-15  example title         5
            another sample title  3
            another one           6
            lorem ipsum           4
            example               2
```